# Relate adhesion value and subsequences limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

> Let $x_{n}$ a sucesion in the space metric $X$. We call $a\in X$ is adhesion value of {$x_{n}$} iff for all neighborhood $V=V(a)$ and for all $n$ in naturals, exists $m\geq n$ such that $x_m \in V$.Prove that the set of adhesion values of {$x_{n}$} matches the set of subsequences limits.

That's my problem, what I tried is defines the set E={$y \in X$ : $y$ is a limit subsequence of {$x_{n}$}} because when I took a $a \in$ E, I know that there is {$x_{n_{k}}$} a subequence of {$x_{n}$} such that {$x_{n_{k}}$} converges to $a$. I used a equivalence with neighborhoods, i.e, for all neighborhood $V=v_{a}$ of $a$, exists $k$ in naturals such that $a_{n} \in V$, fall $n\geq k$. I don't understand how to relate both definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Say, $x_{n_{k}}\rightarrow a$ for some subsequence $(x_{n_{k}})$ of $(x_{n})$. Given $V(a)$, there exists some $K$ such that $x_{n_{k}}\in V(a)$ for $k\geq K$. Since $n_{k}\rightarrow\infty$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$, for any natural $N$ there exists some $K'\geq K$ such that $n_{K'}>N$, so $x_{n_{K'}}\in V(a)$.

For any adherent point $a$. Consider $B(a,1)$, the ball of $a$ with radius $1$, then some $n_{1}\geq 1$ is such that $x_{n_{1}}\in B(a,1)$. Consider instead that $B(a,1/2)$ and $n_{1}+1$, some $n_{2}\geq n_{1}+1$ is such that $x_{n_{2}}\in B(a,1/2)$. Keep in mind that $n_{2}>n_{1}$. Proceed in this way we get $x_{n_{k}}\in B(a,1/k)$, this is a subsequence with limit $a$.